# Invalid google_app_id error on Android with cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics plugin in Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've setup a Cordova app to use the cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics plugin (which uses the cordova-support-google-services plugin). It's working fine for iOS but not Android. On Android, the events are never registered. When I output the logs with "adb logcat" I get the following error:

```
01-02 13:54:57.322 E/FA (18325): Invalid google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See https_/goo.gl/NAOOOI. provided id: 1046165292000
```

Note: I modified the url in the log so Stack Overflow wouldn't complain about url shorteners.

I've added the google-services.json file from the Firebase console and added the com.google.gms plugin line to my build.gradle file (in platforms/android). I'm honestly at a loss as to what to look at next, any thoughts?

Here's the google-services.json file (with identifying data modified)

```
{
    "project_info": {
        "project_number": "1000000000000",
        "firebase_url": "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
        "project_id": "my-app",
        "storage_bucket": "my-app.appspot.com"
    },
    "client": [
        {
            "client_info": {
                "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:1000000000000:android:5da9694e695bed4d",
                "android_client_info": {
                    "package_name": "ca.my.app"
                }
            },
            "oauth_client": [
                {
                    "client_id": "1000000000000-f1l9aikqj3q9fb5bmosdor3acghq60av.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                    "client_type": 3
                }
            ],
            "api_key": [
                {
                    "current_key": "__mykey__"
                }
            ],
            "services": {
                "analytics_service": {
                    "status": 1
                },
                "appinvite_service": {
                    "status": 1,
                    "other_platform_oauth_client": []
                },
                "ads_service": {
                    "status": 2
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: I fixed it by copying the app id from Firebase console (x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxx) to string.xml file like this :  <string name="google_app_id">x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>. Hope that will help you.

Comment: @Rocker23 I have it working now but I remember trying a ton of different things. I vaguely remember it being an issue with an older version of the phonegap-plugin-push plugin that was conflicting with it. Your solution matches what's recommended on the push plugin Github so go ahead and add it as an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Yes same issue with an older version of plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by copying the app id from Firebase console (x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxx) to string.xml file like this :

```
<string name="google_app_id">x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>.
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: Legend!
Been looking all day!